# .kv file and python file not matching up for some reason

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Not sure what the issue is here, I want two buttons on my kivy screen, so on a seperate .kv file I have two buttons under a widgets attribute which I then call in my .py file. Can anyone help me spot what might be wrong please? Thanks.

```
from kivy.app import App
#kivy.require("1.8.0")
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class Widgets(Widget):
    pass


class SimpleKivy2(App):
    def build(self):
        return Widgets()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimpleKivy2().run()
```

here is the .kv file:

```
#File name: k4.py
<Widgets>:
    Button:
        size: 100,75
        pos: 0,0
        text: "Kivy"
        color: 0,1,0,1
        font_size: 40

    Button:
        size: 170,75
        pos: 100,0
        text: "Tutorials"
        color: 1,0,0,1
        font_size: 40
```

My python file's name is "k4.py" my .kv's file name is k4.kv

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default kivy tries to load a kv file named as the App class in lowercase with "App" removed if it appears at the end. So it would load a file named `simplekivy2.kv`. You can also load the kv file excplicitly from a builder as described [in the documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv):

```
Builder.load_file('path/to/file.kv')
```